# Creating anchor tag inside anchor tag

Tags: html

During my random testing I saw a behavior where I put an anchor tag inside another anchor tag. I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3euyA/3/).

```
<a class="groupPopper">
     <a class="name"> content</a>
</a>​
```

But in the developer tool it appears different:

[image]

I believe we cannot put an anchor tag inside another anchor tag as  clicking on the inner anchor will bubble up the click event to the parent anchor tag which should not be allowed.

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

As @j08691 describes, nested `a` elements are forbidden in HTML syntax. HTML specifications do not say why; they just emphasize the rule.

On the practical side, browsers effectively enforce this restriction in their parsing rules, so unlike in many other issues, violating the specs just won’t work. The parsers effectively treat an `<a>` start tag inside an open `a` element as implicitly terminating the open element before starting a new one.

So if you write `<a href=foo>foo <a href=bar>bar</a> zap</a>`, you won’t get nested elements. Browsers will parse it as `<a href=foo>foo</a> <a href=bar>bar</a> zap`, i.e. as two consecutive links followed by some plain text.

There is nothing inherently illogical with nested `a` elements: they could be implemented so that clicking on “foo” or “zap” activates the outer link, clicking on “bar” activates the inner link. But I don’t see a reason to use such a structure, and the designers of HTML probably didn’t see one either, so they decided to forbid it and thereby simplify things.

(If you really wanted to simulate nested links, you could use a normal link as the outer link and a `span` element with a suitable event handler as the inner “link”. Alternatively, you could duplicate links: `<a href=foo>foo</a> <a href=bar>bar</a> <a href=foo>zap</a>`.)

Comment: Seems like at least some of the latest browers allow it now. I have a structure `a > div > a` and Chrome and Firefox both let it exist as I wrote it and they do not unstructure it during parsing (I haven't tested Edge).

Comment: Saying it's not possible is not really helpful, sorry.

Comment: @trusktr I tested it as well and even a structure like `a > div > a` comes out as <a></a><div><a></a></div>, so the browser really does not allow nested links (even if there is a div is between.

Comment: @G.Egli Ah, you're right. I must've overlooked it, or I was doing it with plain JavaScript. The parser does not allow it (what a shame, it should not morph your HTML to something you didn't write, in my opinion). Here's how it can be achieved with JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/0ozfcn1d/

Answer (score 27):

[Nested links are illegal.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)

> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A
>   element must not contain any other A elements.

Comment: What can be the reason behind this? just want more clarification.

Comment: I don't know the precise reasoning behind it, however I would say at least semantically it makes no sense to nest links. Not to mention having actual links with `href` values nested seems completely pointless.

Comment: That is my assumption as well. just wanted to be more sure. as I can put other tag (eg. span) inside A tag.

Comment: It's not pointless at all. Let's say you have an outter anchor styled as a large block-level element. Now somewhere within thatlarge block, at an arbitrary location, you want a single span-level anchor which takes you somewhere else. For example to a #comments shortcut. There's no way to do that without using nested anchors.

Comment: @DanielJames - That makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: In my case i would like to have 2 nested a href's.
<a href="https://google.com">
    <div>
        <span>Some outter element</span>
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
            <span>Some inner element</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</a>
If user click on outer element but not on inner element, then i redirect it to link in the same tab.
If user click on inner element, then i redirect it to the new browser tab.
In my case it is more like UI stuff and i don't want to inject Javascript for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 20):

I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34797422) as @thinkbonobo and found a way to do it without JavaScript:

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
 
.outer > a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
 
.inner {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
 
.inner a {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <a href="#overlay-link"></a>
  <div class="inner">
    You can click on the text of this red box. It also contains a
    <a href="#inner-link">W3C compliant hyperlink.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to make an anchor covering the whole `.outer` div, then giving all other anchors in the inner div a positive `z-index` value. Full credit goes to https://bdwm.be/html5-alternative-nested-anchor-tags/

Answer (score 9):

you can use object tag to solve this problem.
such as

```
<a><object><a></a></object></a>
```

Comment: This works surprisingly well. But is it "legal" according to the spec? The spec is so dense and convoluted it's hard to be certain.

Comment: @mpoisot This is extremely bad practice and hacky. It's definitely not legal or advised in regards to HTML syntax. Read this if you need more info: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

Comment: this works well in windows pc but the link won't be able to be cliked on iPhone with iOS 15.x on Safari. Despise it won't move itself to some strange places due to invalid spec, best not use this hack.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon this issue when trying to make a div panel clickable by also have buttons. The workaround that I recommend is to use javascript events.

Here is a codepen example I created....
http://codepen.io/thinkbonobo/pen/gPxJGV

Here's the html portion of it:

## Example of link embedded in link....

```
<div class=panel onclick="alert('We\'ll hi-ii-ii-ide')">
  If you say run<br>
  <button onclick="app.hitMe(event)">more</button><br>
  <br>
  And if you say hide...<br>
</div>
```

Notice how the event for the inner link is captured and stopPropagation() is used. this is critical to make sure the outer trigger doesn't run.

Comment: I had to use event.preventDefault(); on Chrome

Comment: It has the problem that mmb-click doesn't open the link in a new tab.

Comment: You can also do this without JS, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076345/) below

Answer (score 3):

It is invalid HTML.

You can't nest `a` elements.

So, by definition, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: What can be the reason behind this? just want more clarification.

Comment: @Sushil - Answer me this - what would be the meaning of a nested `a` element? What could it possibly mean?

Comment: Yes, it don't make any sense but it was new thing for me so wanted to be sure as I can put span, img .. tags inside anchor tag.

Comment: @Sushil - Sure, as _content_ it makes sense. Having a _command_ inside a command doesn't.

Comment: @Anoop I know this is a really old thread but I'll offer my advice anyway. My guess as to why you can't nest a tags inside other a tags is because when you go to click the nested link, the browser will detect that two a tags have been clicked simultaneously (the child and the parent). This means they'd need to know some kind of priority like which a tag is more important to follow. Browsers might also handle prioritizing differently to other browsers and it just starts getting unnecessarily tricky to create a spec for it so it's best to just avoid allowing nested a tags all together.

Answer (score 1):

For nested anchors, to prevent the inner event from bubbling up to the outer event, you want to stop propagation as soon as the inner event is clicked.

OnClick of inner event, use e.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 1):

I know It's an old post, but I want to point out that user9147812 answer worked better than any other of the suggestions.
This is how I stacked the whole thing.

```
    <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 border:0;
      outline: 0;
    }

    .outer_anchor {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px 8px;
      margin: 2px;
      border: 1px solid #252632;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: #1c1d26;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #616161;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
      transform: translateY(0);
      transition: background 250ms;
    }
    .inner_anchor {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px 8px;
      margin: 2px;
      border: 1px solid #252632;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background: #1c1d26;
      color: #fff;
      transform: translate(0px);
    }
    .inner_anchor:hover {
      background: #647915;
    }
    </style>


<a href="#">ItemX<object><a class="elim_btn" href="#" title='Eliminate'>&times;</a></object></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like that. I was facing the same issue in my app.
You can simply add `<div>` tag in top and `<a>` tags at child level.
something like:

```
<div id="myDiv"><a href="#"></a>
     <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

make sure you add click event for myDiv in your script file as well.

`window.location.href = "#dashboardDetails";`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest 'a' tags. Instead set outer container as 'position:relative' and second 'a' as 'position:absolute' and increase its z-index value. You'll get the same effect.

```
<div style="position:relative">
<a href="page2.php"><img src="image-1.png"></a>
<a style="position:absolute;top:0;z-index:99" href="page1.php"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
 
.outer > a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
 
.inner {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
 
.inner a {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <a href="#overlay-link"></a>
  <div class="inner">
    You can click on the text of this red box. It also contains a
    <a href="#inner-link">W3C compliant hyperlink.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

This is a bad way of coding but you can try this -

<a href="1">aaaa  <table><tr><td><a href="2">bbbb  </a></td></tr></table> </a>

Comment: As well as looking like a browser hack from 1996, this would not work. In Firefox at least, it would try to make sense of this by closing the outside anchor when it finds the start of the inside anchor. That would also involve closing the td, td, and table elements, and then reopening them all again after the inner anchor is closed. I've seen this exact behaviour in a WooCommerce template, casuing some pretty funky and non-obvious formatting issues, which led me to this SO question trying to find an answer.