# Why is corrupted dom treeview for span in a tag?

Tags: html, css, dom, treeview

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
        Link-1
        <span class="sub-list hidden">
            <a href="#">SubLink-1</a>
            <a href="#">SubLink-2</a>
            <a href="#">SubLink-3</a>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">Link-2</a>
    <a href="#">Link-3</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    height: 25px;
}

.wrapper > a {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: none;
    float: right;
    display: block;
}


.sub-list {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    width: 251px;
    height: 40px;
    border-right: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-left: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vAQF/1/

I want to create a menu and submenu. But when I place submenu under the a tag with a span wrapper, dom treeview appears corrupted as below image;
[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nesting links within a link, which is forbidden:

> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A
>   element must not contain any other A elements.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

[Creating anchor tag inside anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag)