# move element with child text into another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

As you can see from this snip I have an `<a>` and an `<h4>` with a child of `<a>` that matches the 1st `<a>` on the snip. What I am trying to do is take the `<h4>` with the text of the nested `<a>` and place it into the top level `<a>`. So the final product will be `<a><h4>text</h4></a>`. I have tried using jQuery with appendTo but it does not render the markup that I am after. How can I get the desired markup?

The jQuery code that I currently have created is `jQuery(".panel-group .text-danger").appendTo( jQuery("a[href='#collapseOne']"));`

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <a class="panel-heading visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne"></a>
  <h4 class="text-danger">
    <a class="panel-heading visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">Urgent</a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your situation.  Are both elements always visible?  Do you want the child `<a><h4>` combo to be removed after being moved upwards?  Your requirements may better be solved in a different way if we knew more information / had a working example.

Comment: Currently both elements are being shown. What I am trying to do is grab the `<h4>` and the text from inside the `<a>` and place it into the `<a>` tag that is equal with the `<h4>` tag.

Comment: So, if we name them, `H4.Parent`, and `H4.Child`, you want to leave the contents of `H4.Child` in-tact always (and always visible) and replace the text contents of `H4.Parent.A` with the text contents of `H4.Child.A`, correct (in other words, you want to copy the `H4.Child` into the `H4.Parent` without bringing the `H4.Child.A` element, just it's contents)?  Also, is this on click, or on page load?

Comment: I would say that I have `A.Parent` and `H4.Parent` What I am wanting to do is take the text from `H4.parent.a` and move it into `H4.Parent` (removing the `.a`). I then want to move `H4.parent` into `A.parent` (removing `H4.parent`). So the final product will be `<div><a class="parent"><h4 class="old-parent">text</h4></a></div>` I do not care the order that things happen to reach the final goal and this would need to happen on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to `clone` the node (which can be done in pure JavaScript or JQuery) and perform your operations on it in memory before applying it to the DOM.  You'll also need a more specific selector than the `a[href='#collapseOne']` because the change will be applied to more than one DOM node in your example because multiple nodes will match this selector (unless that is intentional).

- For JQuery cloning: http://api.jquery.com/clone/
- For Javascript cloning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode

You can clone a node using syntax similar to this:

```
var clonedNode = $("#idSelector").clone();

clonedNode.html(""); // Clears the content of the clone, not the DOM element
```

### Example Logic

1. Store text of the hyperlink in a variable
2. Get a cloned copy of the `H4` node.
3. Truncate the contents of the cloned `H4` node.
4. Replace the contents of the cloned node with the hyperlink text.
5. Update the target element with the new hybrid node.

### Example Code:

```js
$(function() {
    //Add a click event to each .panel-heading element below an H4
    //This could be removed for the code to run on page-load the references would simply need to be updated.
    $("H4").on("click", ".panel-heading", function(e, data) {
        var linkText = $(this).text(); // Get the text of the link we want
        var clonedNode = $(this).closest("H4").clone(); // Should grab the parent H4 of the hyperlink that was clicked and make a copy.
        clonedNode.html(""); // truncate the contents of the cloned node
        clonedNode.text(linkText); // Set the link text of the H4
        $(".panel").find(".parent-link").html(clonedNode);
    });
    
    //for no click event the logic is the same, but the selectors change.
});
```

```css
.parent-link {
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
}
H4 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <a class="panel-heading visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block parent-link" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne"></a>
  <h4 class="text-danger">
    <a class="panel-heading visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">Urgent</a>
  </h4>
      <h4 class="text-normal">
    <a class="panel-heading visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">Normal</a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Or if you prefer external resources: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/yykbfd7b/

I have added some CSS to highlight the parent node whose contents are ultimately replaced.  I also added a CSS class (`parent-link`) to your parent link to make it easier to select.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot logically place a block level element `<h4>` inside an inline element `<a>` according to HTML Standards. So, you need to find some alternate ways of doing it. It is simply NOT VALID HTML (Except HTML 5).

And another thing is, you cannot nest `<a>` inside another `<a>`!

For the comment by [vsync](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104380/vsync), please check out [Creating anchor tag inside anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13052598/462627).

Comment: I didn't say anything about anchor inside anchor. I was referring to your original post, before you've edited it to something different.

Comment: I just added the nested `<a>` and I haven't changed any original content. `:)` *ps: No personal ego*! *`;)`*

Comment: @PraveenKumar What? Sure they can. Check [here](http://validator.w3.org/check) with the string `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>aaa</title></head><body><a><h4>header</h4></a></body></html>`.

Comment: @MaxArt `Line 1, Column 171: document type does not allow element "h4" here; missing one of "button", "map", "object", "ins", "del", "noscript" start-tag`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar According to W3, a tags are pretty flexible (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html) as far as the content they can contain (in the HTML5 spec) and are largely dependent on the parent of the `<a>` tag.  The W3 says that it is `transparent`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#transparent, and as a result an H4 nested within is technically valid (the Validator service confirms this).  Whether or not this markup communicates the intent of the author accurately or indicates a lack of understanding is a different issue.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is valid in HTML5, and almost a lot of invalid stuffs are valid in HTML5.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not only it's valid HTML5, but old browsers can handle it just fine - and that's what we care about after all. We can discuss if this is *semantically* correct, but that's another story.

Comment: @MaxArt Agreed with you. Let's not hijack this topic. I guess we are arguing something too much! `:)` Even though I know these things are possible and valid in HTML5, yes, the part you said *semantically not valid*, that's where I am!

Comment: @EveryoneAbove: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/of6o5gg5/. Check this using Inspect Element.

Comment: @xDaevax Updated the answer with negating HTML 5. `:)`

Comment: I am going to stop all of this crazy stuff and state that I am developing inside of HTML5 and that everything I am doing is pure HTML5 per company policy `:D` I also have made a comment that hopefully will clear up my OP and better explain what I am trying to do.