# In the ordered sequence of words: "Word1, Word2, Word3": how to have 1 and only 1 hyperlink on "Word1" & "Word3"? Thus, skip a word in a single link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

## How to skip a word in a hyperlink?

Imagine a random ordered sequence of words:

`...` `Word 1` `Word 2` `Word3` `...`

How would it be possible to have **1 unifying** (i.e. not 2 seperate links) **hyperlink** on `Word 1 & Word 3`?

I.e.: when one hovers either `Word 1` or `Word 3`, the spectator can immediately notice that the hyperlink will lead to a page that covers the meaning of both these words (visible by whatever the *CSS* of `a:hover` is in a particular document).

## The result would be:

`...` **`Word 1`** `Word 2` **`Word3`** `...`

*CRUCIAL REMARK:* But then instead of having 2 seperate (in this case **bold-formatted hyperlinks**), they would be **unified** into 1 single hyperlink. Again: this could e.g. be visualised in *CSS* by having a `text-decoraiton:underline` on `a:hover`, covering **`Word 1`** and **`Word 3`** simultaneously.

## Optionally:

It would be good to also have the possibility to add a **second, other hyperlink** to `Word 2`.

---

## Use-case example:

In the sentence:

> "This does not need any open `(Word 1)` bladder `(Word 2)` surgeries `(Word 3)`."

It would be nice to have **1 unifying hyperlink** on `Word 1` and `Word3`. This example clarifies the usefulness of such a *word-skipping-hyperlink*: `Word 2` certainly shouldn't be included in the first unifying link, since the *urinary bladder-Wikipedia* han't got much to do with the *open surgeries-Wikipedia*.

## The result would be:

> "This does not need any [open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasiveness_of_surgical_procedures#Open_surgery) bladder [surgeries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasiveness_of_surgical_procedures#Open_surgery)."

*CRUCIAL REMARK:* Instead that the hyperlink on **open** and **surgeries** should be **unified** into one single hyperlink.

## Optionally:

It would be good to also have the possibility to add a **second, other hyperlink** to `Word 2`:

> "This does not need any [open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasiveness_of_surgical_procedures#Open_surgery) [bladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urinary_bladder) [surgeries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasiveness_of_surgical_procedures#Open_surgery)."

The *CRUCIAL REMARK* from above, also applies here.

Comment: You should make 3 hyperlinks.

Comment: @NETCreator - Unfortunately, then, they would not be **unified**, since they would not be **visualized simultaneously**, specified by the mark-up in *CSS*. --- Is your guess that this is impossible?

Comment: What problem is that going to solve? Explain the actual use case. What you explained it so far doesn't strike me as particularly useful. Also, it's not possible to do such a thing in CSS alone, you will need the help of Javascript.

Comment: @Tomalak - Thank you for your comment, I will add the *Javascript* tag to the question, as well as the explanation of a facility and use case.

Comment: I don't see any use case described.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Cf. the use, together with an example can be found below the *horizontal line*, starting from the heading "**Use-case example:**", e.g. `"This does not need any open bladder surgeries."`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have *one link* that spans two separate words.

You can have one link on each of the words point to the same location and use a little bit of JavaScript to highlight all the links that have the same destination when the user hovers over one.

For convenience I'm using jQuery here, but the same thing isn't difficult to do without it.

```js
$(function () {
    function getKey(element) {
        return element.href;
    }
    function sameGroupAs(element) {
        var key = getKey(element);
        return function () {
            return getKey(this) === key;
        }
    }
    
    $(document)
    .on("mouseenter", "a", function () {
        $("a").filter(sameGroupAs(this)).addClass("active");
    })
    .on("mouseleave", "a", function () {
        $("a").filter(sameGroupAs(this)).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
a.active {
    background-color: #A8C5FF;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>"This does not need any <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasiveness_of_surgical_procedures#Open_surgery" rel="nofollow">open</a> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urinary_bladder" rel="nofollow">bladder</a> <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasiveness_of_surgical_procedures#Open_surgery" rel="nofollow">surgeries</a>."</p>
```

I've used the href as a grouping key, but you can use any other method of groping. Just modify the `getKey()` function.

Comment: That is material for a separate question. Ask just this in a new post, ideally without referring to this question at all.

Comment: No, I don't think so, because your follow-up question really is *"How can I highlight a link on first click and follow it on second click?"*. This is completely separate from this question.

Answer (score 1):

With Javascript it's easy - create a span for each word, style the two outer spans to look like links, and attach a single click function to both spans.

HTML

```html
<span id = "one">one,</span>
<span id = "two">two,</span>
<span id = "three">three</span>
```

CSS

```css
#one, #three {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

jQuery

```js
$('#one, #three').click(function() {
    location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
});
$('#one, #three').hover(function() {
    $('#one, #three').css('text-decoration', 'underline');}, function(){
    $('#one, #three').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you are heading in the right direction! However, would it be possible to have the mark-up `text-decoration:none` on the hyperlink, and have `text-decoration:underline` on `hyperlink:hover` (i.e. after hover)? --- **The *CSS*:** `#one,#three{text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer}
#one:hover,#three:hover{text-decoration:underline}` **isn't giving the desired result**, since the *CSS* still doesn't recognize `#one` and `#three` as being **unified**, in contrast with the *JS*. Many thanks for any additional help.

Comment: Yes - please see my update (crossed with your comment) - this now includes a hover effect.  You can swap the bold/normal for underline/no underline

Comment: I've edited the code to provide as you suggest - the underlines appear under both on hover on either word.

Comment: Perfect result, many thanks! --- Just an additional remark for other implementors of your help: the code only seems to work (at least when I just tried in *JSfiddle*) when one activates the *JS* **jQuery-library**.

Comment: @sideroxylon why would you use javascript to style a hover state?

Comment: @Tomalak I read the question.. this answer doesn't handle the ID's dynamically, therefor if you already have span #one, #two, #three.. you could just as easily style these with CSS.. how am I wrong?

Comment: @webkit so that both #one and #three get the styling regardless of which is hovered

Comment: @webkit You cant highlight element B when you hover the mouse over element A with CSS alone. That's why you need Javascript. (Though I think this answer is not a particularly good way to solve the problem.)

Comment: @Tomalak thank you.. I missed that part.. if we only had 'previous sibling selectors'.. =)

Comment: @webkit Would not help. As I understand the question, the other link could appear anywhere on the page. It's not generally sensible to solve this with CSS.

Comment: @sideroxylon - Thank you for your help. Your answer is very elegant, but many other good answers are added as well. I find it hard to choose "the best answer". --- The main addition your answer could use is the adding of a **second, other** hyperlink to `Word 2` (i.c.: "[bladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urinary_bladder)"); which is not present in your current answer, but is a feature of other answers present.

Comment: Just add a click function to it - `('#two').click(function() {location.href = 'http://www.yahoo.com';});`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure HTML + CSS method.  The trick is applying a negative z-index to the second word.  That makes it unclickable:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a span:nth-child(1), a span:nth-child(3) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover span:nth-child(1), a:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a span:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
This does not need any
<a href="">
  <span>open</span>
  <span>bladder</span>
  <span>surgeries</span>
</a>
.
```

If you want the second word to have a different link, I think you need to duplicate the HTML, making the first instance `position: absolute`, and the second word of the second instance `position: relative`.  You can then change formatting based on hover:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#a1 {
  position: absolute;
}

#a2 span:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
}

#a1:hover span:nth-child(1), #a1:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#a2:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
This does not need any
<a id="a1" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasiveness_of_surgical_procedures#Open_surgery">
  <span>open</span>
  <span>bladder</span>
  <span>surgeries</span>
</a>

<a id="a2" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urinary_bladder">
  <span>open</span>
  <span>bladder</span>
  <span>surgeries</span>
</a>
.
```

Comment: That solves the OPs request verbatim but isn't in any way flexible or fit for real-world use.

Comment: @Rick Hitchcock - Thank you for your answer. Seems like another good and inventive way of tackling he problem, which can spare out *JS*. --- However, I have 1 question: the lay-out is working just fine, but is it possible to implement working links into your code, both a single 1 for **[open & surgeries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasiveness_of_surgical_procedures#Open_surgery)** and a different 1 for **[bladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urinary_bladder)**, or are there some difficulties in adding this feature of having 2 *inter-laced* links?

Comment: That's tricky and I guess it explains Tomalak's comment.  I tried adding an `<a href` within the `<a href`, but the first `</a>` closed both.

Comment: I've come up with a solution, but it duplicates the HTML content.

Comment: Nicely done! Ok, I seem understand [Tomalak](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)'s comment now. It seems to be the same difficulty I am describing in a **comment on [rb_x](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1318403/rb-x)'s answer**, which he now has seemed to overcome.

Answer (score 1):

using pure **CSS**, you can have one link that spans multiple words, and have only some of them clickable.
(and you can make it look nicer than my demo using some more **CSS**)

This answer doesn't fully meet the OP needs because it doesn't allow a different link within the context of the first link, but it's still worth mentioning.

In order to have one link **only** that spans multiple words, and also have a nested element that points to another link, we'd have to allow anchor tag nesting, [but it's not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag), the best way to achieve the same behavior is to split the "big" anchor tag to pieces (manually or with **JS** like suggested in other answers)].

```css
a span
{
    color: black;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">first <span>second</span> third</a>
```

Comment: @avrahamcool - Great. Would it be possible as well to adjust the code a bit, to have an optional **second, different** link added to `Word 2` (i.c. the word: "*second*")?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen I think not. mainly because you cant have [**nested anchor tags**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag). your case requires different anchor tags (and you can do so using **JS** as suggested in other answers)

Comment: @avrahamcool - Thank you for this adept reference. Perhaps it's usefull to add this to your answer, before the comment will decay?

Comment: @avrahamcool - Thanks a lot. [rb_x](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1318403/rb-x) seems to have found a work-around in his answer, using a `<span onclick="document.location.href = '...'` as a substitute for a nested anchor tag.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen indeed, that's what i meant by "(and you can do so using **JS** as suggested in other answers)"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to go is maybe this css rule:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
}
span { 
    color:black;
    cursor:default;
}
```

and a short inline js onclick event where you don't want the event propagated:

```
<span onclick="return false;"> Word2 </span>
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lux1xe6j/3/)

But don't do that in production.
It's pointless and ugly.

---

If you want the second link inside the first one, for the sake of simplicity, i would do this:

```
<span onclick="document.location.href = 'YOUR_2ND_LINK_HERE'; return false;"> Word2 </span>
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lux1xe6j/5/)

---

Here you go then
[new fiddle with visual hint](http://jsfiddle.net/Lux1xe6j/7/)

Comment: I actually like the answer in your JSFiddle very much for its simplicity. I don't see the problem "in production" right away. :) Perhaps the adding of a difference (e.g. from no-underline to underline) on hover, would add something to it, but that seems possible. --- But, more importantly: do you think it's possible as well to add a second, different hyperlink on `Word 2`?

Comment: How would one go about? If I wrap an additional hyperlink around `Word 2`, there appears a link; but when clicked, it seems to redirect to the same hyperlink of `Word 1` and `Word 3`, instead of to a different webpage.

Comment: I updated my answer and the jsFiddle to reflect what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, very nice work-around for the [nested anchor tages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag)-problem. --- However, regarding the unifying: even though the link of `Word 1` and `Word 3` are unified in code, this is not reflected **visually to the end-user** yet (which could be done by collectively changing from no-underline to underline on hover). --- Or to be more precise: you have all the same reflected that by changing the colors, but instead it could be good for lay-out coherency, to have the same color for all hyperlinks in a document.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to this answer. However, the issue that I'm addressing is that your answer currently doesn't feature a collective change (simultaneously `Word 1` & `Word3`) on hovering over 1 of these words (this can e.g. be done by going from `text-decoration:` `none` to `underline`, as in [Rick Hitchcock](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3903374/rick-hitchcock)'s solution. --- Sideroxylon's solution can feature this as well, when one changes its *CSS* a bit. --- It can also be done with color, like in [tomalak](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want to achieve then:

**Html:**

```
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">
    <span class="d">Link 1</span> 
    <span class="b">Link 2</span> 
    <span class="d">Link 1</span> 
    <span class="b">Link 2</span>
    <span class="d">Link 1</span> 
    <span class="b">Link 2</span> 
</a>
```

**Css**

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.d {
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.d.fake-hover {
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.b {
    color:darkRed;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.b.fake-hover {
    background:darkRed;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('d');
var otherElems = document.getElementsByClassName('b');
var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var _href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';

function fakeIt(what, el) {
    var els = (el.classList.contains('d')) ? elems : otherElems;
    for (var i = 0, x = els.length; i < x; i++) {
        (what == 'hover') ? els[i].classList.add('fake-hover') : els[i].classList.remove('fake-hover');
    }
}

function addCustomLink(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = _href;
}

for (var i = 0, x = allElems.length; i < x; i++) {
    var el = allElems[i];
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        fakeIt('hover', e.target);
    });
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
        fakeIt('out', e.target);
    });
    if (el.className == 'b') {
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            addCustomLink(e);
        });
    }
};
```

In jsFiddle apparently I can't use document.location.href so you have to manually edit the addCustomLink function.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/stn92bnw/15/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your experience is clearly much higher than your formal reputation, which will go up quickly. However, my experience is far smaller, so e.g. I still have some troubles getting the `location.href = www.google.com;` to work...