# Anchor inside a UL LI breaks functionality

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a hover library to create an animation when the user hovers over a `<li>`

Here's a sample:

```
<ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <div>
                    <span>My Muse by Zachary Horst</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
...
</ul>
```

Here's the working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/95Lsafhe/

All is well up till here.

However as soon as I add an anchor below the `<span>`, everything goes for a toss.

```
<ul id="da-thumbs" class="da-thumbs">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <div>
                    <span>My Muse by Zachary Horst</span>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Add button</a>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
...
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/95Lsafhe/1/

I am not sure what is breaking the functionality? I just want to display anchor buttons below the span when the use hovers on a `<li>`.

**Update:** From the comments, I have learned that an anchor cannot be nested within another. I want an anchor directly below the span. However I am **OK** if the outer anchor is deleted/removed. Can you tell me how to change my css/code to make this happen. The span and button have to visible only on hover.

Comment: anchor inside anchor element is not a validated html. and the hover library is not accepting this. You can convert anchor to other element instead of anchor.

Comment: You can check this example. http://jsfiddle.net/95Lsafhe/3/

Comment: **[Why you cannot create anchor inside anchor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHat you are doing is wrong you cannot nest html anchor tag It is invalid HTML.

So, by definition, the behaviour is undefined.
```

[Changed Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/95Lsafhe/1/)

Just bring the anchor tag below the intial one

```
<a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            <div>
                <span>My Muse by Zachary Horst</span>

            </div>
        </a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default AddAnchor">Add button</a>
```

**EDIT:-**

> Work Around you can use span inside the div and emulate the function of anchor tag by firing a click event and inside it use jQuery.get() Method to make HTTP GET Request

[Demo with Anchor tag emulated with span](http://jsfiddle.net/95Lsafhe/8/)

Comment: Thanks. I want an anchor directly below the span. However I am OK if the outer anchor is deleted/removed. Can you tell me how to change my css/code to make this happen.

Comment: By the way I am trying to avoid adding a click() event to the anchor otherwise your solution is good. Please check the update I have added to my question.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid click event is there any specific reason ??

Answer (score 0):

Nested `<a>` are illegal so you can change `<a>` to `<button>`

```
<a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
                <div>
                    <span>My Muse by Zachary Horst</span>
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add button</button>
                </div>
            </a>
```