# Placing anchor element inside an anchor element

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if HTML code is valid:

```
<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">
   <a href="www.other.com" target=_blank">OTHER</a>
   <div>Example</div>
</a>
```

What other can it be done if it's not valid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13052598/4741567

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Don't make it!!! forbidden syntax and also go to jail if police see this post. Two links in the same zone. It's like the world turns around in two directions at the same time.

Comment: why cant you split it into two like `<a href="www.other.com" target=_blank">OTHER</a><a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">
   <div>Example</div>
</a>`

Answer (score 2):

No, this code is *not* valid. Links fall into the category of "interactive content," and cannot (per the specification) contain any elements that are also within the category of "interactive content".

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element