# cakephp make div a link

Tags: html, css, cakephp

I have the below div that gets drawn in a loop to list a number of assets set to a view

I have so far added a link for the image and also for the link text under the `caption` div. However, I want to make the entire div of class `"col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-6"` into a clickable link for mobile devices. Wrapping the `div` in an `a` tag is only applying it to the image and not the rest of the div. How do I achieve this?

```
 <?php echo "<a href={$url}>";
            ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <div>
                            <!-- image -->
                            <?php echo $this->Html->image(Hash::get($a, 'image'), array(
                                'class' => 'assetImg cover',
                                'alt' => Hash::get($a, 'alt_tag'),
                                'title' => Hash::get($a, 'alt_tag')
                            )); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4>
                                <?php
                                    echo $this->Html->link(Hash::get($a, 'model_name'), array(
                                        'controller' => Hash::get($a, 'url'),
                                        'action' => Hash::get($a, "id"),
                                    ));
                                ?>
                            </h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-4">Price:</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-8"><?php echo $this->Number->currency((Hash::get($a, 'sale_price', 0)), 'EUR', array(
                                        'zero' => 'POA',
                                        'places' => 0,
                                        'thousands' => ","
                                    )); ?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-4">Year:</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-8"><?php echo Hash::get($a, 'year') ?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-4">Hours:</div>
                                <div class="col-xs-8"><?php echo Hash::get($a, 'hours') ?></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
```

Comment: Are you want to wrap complete div in anchor tag or only image ?

Comment: The complete div in an anchor

Comment: You have already anchor in div .Nested anchor is not possible. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag

Comment: Nested anchor problem. Thanks

Comment: hi plz accept my ans . kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already anchor in div .Nested anchor is not possible. 
Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A element must not contain any other A elements. 
check this 
[Creating anchor tag inside anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag)