# link tag inside sidebar is not working

Tags: html, css

i build a sidebar wich includes a notification center, inside of it are contents, status updates etc. the problem is that I can not click on them

```
<div class="media notification-conent">
   <a href="#">
      <div class="media-left">
   <a href="#">
   <img class="media-object notification-img" src="img/users/noti_avatar22.jpg">
   </a>
   </div>
   <div class="media-body notification-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading content-header">Anouk hat deine Anfrage abgelehnt</h4>
      <small class="pull-right timestamp">09:17</small>
      <p>Maxim Shooting wurde von Anouk De Heer abgelehnt.</p>
   </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

thats the html from one of the content blocks. The links around the `image` and the timestamp are working but the main link, the one after the content with the class `.notification-content` is not working

when I check the console, I can see that the  link is closed, right after the opening tag. Why is that happening ?

[image: preview]

here is a jsfiddle with the whole styles from the sidebar, and even there is this problem. Hope someone could help me out.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/15dz2k45/)

Comment: Quentin's answer is correct. More information can be found at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/): A link cannot contain another link.

Error recovery in the browser is closing the outer link at the last opportunity it has to stop the inner link being inside it.