# Why does an <a> parent with a list of <a> inside render children separately

Tags: html, nested, anchor

I think I might be going insane. If I have this HTML (I need the section there, in fact there will be multiple sections):

```
<a>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li>foo</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</a>
```

It renders like this:

[image: First html render]

But if I surround the `foo` with an `<a>` tag, to make it a hyperlink, like this:

```
<a>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</a>
```

Everything goes to absolute hell:

[image: Second html render]

I have a feeling is something really dumb I'm overlooking, but what on earth is going on here.

Try it yourself:

```html
<a>
  <section>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</a>
```

Comment: You should not have `<a>` tags wrapped inside of each other. But I didn't know that the browser completely messes it up.

Comment: Here's an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13054959/3233827

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Thanks, I did not know that, and frankly it sounds really stupid. But oh well, if you place the comment as an answer I will select it, if not you can mark this as a duplicate.