# HTML <form> with multiple <a>

Tags: html

thanks in advance for your help.

I have some code that has an `<a href>xxxxx</a>` inside of a larger block of code which consists of divs inside of an `<a>xxxxx</a>` block, like this:

```
<a href=...>
   <div>
      xxxxxxx
   </div>
   <div>
      <a href=...>xxxxxx</a>
   </div>
   <div>
      xxxxx
   </div>
</a>
```

note:  in this case both `<a>` actually use the same href URL, the reason there are two `<a>` is that the first `<a>` already existed prior to surrounding the larger page area with `<a href="...">` functionality

the problem is that i now need to use a `<form>` with hidden values and i am unclear as to where and how to place the `<form>` so that the user clicks definitely pass the hidden form parameters to the url

thanks again.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but you definitely **cannot** have an anchor within an anchor.  If the href of both are the same then you shouldn't need the second, nested anchor.  As for hidden fields, I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: Not only is that code invalid, Chrome (and probably other browsers) will not even render that HTML. The second `div` is moved outside of the outer `a`.

Comment: @Turnip chrome will actually render it, but not in the way as expected. For example `<a href=""><div>...</div></a>` will become `<a href=""></a><div>...</div>`. It will put div outside of anchor. Same for other block-level elements.

Comment: @debute yes. That's what I said above.

Answer (score 0):

First, using a link inside a link (`a` tags) makes no sense and is a no-go. Erase the inner link - wherever you click inside the outer link, the link will work anyway - no need for an inner link if it has the same target.

Second, if you mean to transmit parameters ("hidden form values") when you click that link, I wouldn't use a form, but append these values to the linked URL (like `http://example.com/page1.php?par1=abc&par2=xyz`, so that they can be received as `GET` parameters by the target page.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your great advice and feedback.  (I am a great coder but weak at HTML... so all help is much appreciated!)...