# Why is my html popping outside of the parent?

Tags: html

I am trying to create an `a` element where the whole thing is a link. Inside, I want an image (an `img`) and some text (another `a`). However, when I create this, the second `a` element does not become a child of the first; they're just siblings.

```html
<a class="boxlink" href=".">
  <img src="http://cdn.akc.org/content/hero/puppy-boundaries_header.jpg" height="100">
  <a>Why is this outside the parent?</a>
</a>
```

[image]

As you can see in the inspection, the `</a>` gets moved from after the second `a` element to before it. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: You can't put an anchor `<a>` element inside another one. You're probably better off using a `<span>` or `<p>`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the HTML is invalid. HTML should always be put through the validator for error checking first.

Comment: The second anchor open tag terminates the first anchor element, since the parser knows anchors aren't allowed in anchors. The extra close tag is is ingored. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag

Comment: You have violated three fundamental posting requirements and I have pointed them out to you. Apparently you did not take [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as suggested when you signed up. Nor did you read any of the posting rules I linked to for you. That you don't know how to test for HTML errors indicates you have a bad learning resource or you ignored those instructions also. This is not a fault of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link cannot contain another link. Your second `<a>` tag is getting moved outside of your first `<a>` tag because having an `<a>` tag inside of another `<a>` tag makes no sense; it's [**invalid markup**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). It's getting moved because your parser is smart enough to spot this invalid syntax, and 'correct' it to the most appropriate valid syntax.

To resolve this, you need to move your second `<a>` tag outside of your first `<a>` tag (just as your parser is doing). From there it's just a matter of styling your page with CSS to control where the two links appear.

If you want an image with multiple 'points' that you can click on, you're looking for the **[`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)** tag:

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Hope this helps! :)