# HTML: How to href to a specific URL in a wrapper <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have two small issues .

1. I have a `<a>` Tag wrapper href to `/detail`. In this tag, I have another `<a>` tag to href to `/user`. Do I need set attribute or something for href to `/user`?
2. With button in `<a>` tag href to `/detail`, how can I fire an event without href continue?

My Code:

```
<a href="/detail">
  <a href="/user">Route to User</a> <!-- Is this right? -->
  <button @click="reportUser()">Report this user</button> <!-- How can I fire event report without href to /detail -->
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide code of your html

Comment: First of all, you need to put your code in the question. That horrendous image doesn't help. Secondly, if I understand what you're saying, you have an anchor `<a></ a>` that has anchors and buttons in it? No no no.

Comment: @Justcode and gforce Please check my code

Comment: why anchor inside anchor? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13054959/2630817

Comment: this is a very bad structure but if you want to have it or can not change it,then you can achieve what you want by position and z-index. that is the only way so you can only click a button but href will not effect or clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.topMostAnchor {
        background-color: red;
      height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    }

    .innerAnchor {
       background-color: yellow;
       position: absolute;
       top: 20px;
       z-index: 9;
       left: 10%;
    }

    button {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
       bottom: 20px;
       z-index: 9;
       left: 10%;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="/detail" class="topMostAnchor">
      <a href="/user" class="innerAnchor">Route to User</a> <!-- Is this right? -->
      <button @click="reportUser()">Report this user</button> <!-- How can I fire event report without href to /detail -->
    </a>
```

this is a very bad structure but if you want to have it or can not change it,then you can achieve what you want by position and z-index. that is the only way so you can only click a button but href will not effect or clicked.
Enjoy