# How to use "a" tag inside another "a" tag?

Tags: html, css

```css
.myclass {
width:25%;
height:50px;
background:#888;
display:inline-block;
}
a {
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example1.com">
  <div class="myclass">
    <img src="" />
  <a href="http://example2.com">link</a>
  </div>
</a>



<a href="http://example1.com">
  <div class="myclass">
    <img src="" />
  <a href="http://example2.com">link</a>
  </div>
</a>


<a href="http://example1.com">
  <div class="myclass">
    <img src="" />
  <a href="http://example2.com">link</a>
  </div>
</a>
```

How to use "a" tag inside another "a" tag?

In my code , first href="http://example1.com" does not working.
How do I edit my code?

Thanks

Comment: Nested `a` elements are forbidden in HTML syntax. Look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag

Comment: And why would you even want that?

Comment: there is one simple question: Why would you need smth like that?

Comment: maybe he needs something like 1 large element which, if clicked, will take you to one location. However, if you click a sub element, it would take you somewhere else. But nesting anchor tags is definitely not an option for this

Comment: Because there is a general link for product descriptions.
And a button link to buy directly

Comment: Using onclick has a negative impact?

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

It is explicitly forbidden by [the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

> Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants.

---

If you want overlapping links (and I *really* wouldn't recommend it as the UI will be confusing at best) then you have two options:

- Don't nest. Use CSS to make them overlap (e.g. a negative margin)
- Use JavaScript (a click event listener) to handle one of the interactions (note that this creates even more accessibility issues, e.g. when the user can't operate a mouse)