# HTML Validation w3 Validator

Tags: html

I’m validating my website for W3C validator.
I get this error on Firefox:
Start tag "a" seen but and element of the same type was already open.
End tag "a" violates nesting roles.
End tag "a" violates nesting roles.
this is my code:

```
 <div class="products_index_plus">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"  src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(), $settings['sigma_image_size']); ?>">
        <?php if ('yes' == $settings['sigma_show_badge']) : ?>
            <div class="sigma-wc-products-badge">
                <?php woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>       
        <!-- popup content -->
        <?php if($settings['sigma_open_thumb_in_popup'] === 'yes') :
        ?>
            <div class="sigma-wc-product-popop">
        <div class="sigma-fast-preview" data-product-id="<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>">
        <a class="sigma-wc-product-popop--link"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>         
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nested links are forbidden. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052598/creating-anchor-tag-inside-anchor-tag

Comment: It's usually easier to debug such issues by inspecting the generated markup ("View Source" in the browser) instead of PHP source. In this case, `<a class="sigma-wc-product-popop--link">` seems to be the cause. Since it has no `href`, why not replacing it with a different tag, e.g. `span`?