# Laravel Livewire anchor tags added/repeated in rendered markup

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-livewire

I have the below blade file that has a foreach loop. I've noticed that livewire is repeating the anchor tag within the markup and I don't know why. I've using `wire:key` and it's unique to the page. I even added `wire:key` to the anchor itself but it's still doing it. Has anyone else ever seen this, and if so, how do I fix it? I'm totally lost.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="row">
        @foreach ($templates as $template)
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-3 mb-4" wire:key="template-id-{{ $template->id }}">
                <a href="{{ route('locations.request', ['location' => $location, 'request' => $template]) }}" wire:key="template-link-{{ $template->id }}">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h5 class="text-uppercase">{{ $template->request_name }}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h6><i class="mdi mdi-checkbox-marked-circle h5 text-muted me-2"></i>0</h6>
                            @if ($template->frequency_type_id == 2)
                                <h6><i class="mdi mdi-calendar-clock h5 text-muted me-2"></i>Runs weekly on {{ jddayofweek($template->start_day_of_wek, 1) }}s</h6>
                            @else
                                <h6><i class="mdi mdi-calendar-clock h5 text-muted me-2"></i>Monthly on the {{ $template->ordinal_frequency }} day</h6>
                            @endif

                            <h6><i class="mdi mdi-calendar-check h5 text-muted me-2"></i>Next run on {{ Helper::dateForHumans($template->next_run_date) }}</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <a role="button" id="delete-btn-{{ $template->id }}" class="delete-btn btn btn-outline-danger btn-xs me-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#confirmDelete">
                                    Delete
                                </a>

                                <a role="button" id="enable-btn-{{ $template->id }}" class="icon-button {{ $template->is_enabled ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger' }} me-2" wire:click="toggleEnabled({{ $template->id }})" data-tippy-content="{{ $template->is_enabled ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled' }}">
                                    <i class="mdi mdi-power h3"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

And here's what comes out as the rendered html from dev tools (the green outline is the one that should be there, all the others are a mystery to me:

[image]

If I comment out the anchor tag, all the "phantom" tags go away, so I know it's related to the anchor tag and not some other aspect of the markup.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like it's the `card-footer` div, or the anchor tags inside it. If I comment those out, the extra markup goes away. I've tried adding `wire:key="{{ uniqid() }}"` just as a test to those links and to the `card-footer` div and it doesn't do anything. I'm very confused.

**UPDATE 2:**

I changed the first `<a>` tag in the `card-footer` to a button, and now the first issue is gone, but the button now doesn't work correctly. It shows the confirmation modal as intended, but also registers the link click of the outer anchor tag and then navigates to the `locations.request` route.

I know I've done this in other places before, so I'm confused as to why this time it's not working.

I'm just going to not make the card a link, and just have a link to view it. Frustrating.

Comment: What is `dd($templates);`? Because if there are multiple of the same ID, then you need to specify more than just the ID in your `wire:key`, since the value to that attribute should be entirely unique.

Comment: Also, is that your entire view?

Comment: $template->id is the key from the database table, so it's unique. This is not the entire view, but I've tried commenting out everything else in the view so all that's left is the root div container and the markup I showed in the question, and it's still the same behavior.

Comment: I've done @dd($templates) and reviewed each item and all ids are unique.

Comment: I also tried adding wire:key="{{ uniqid() }}" to basically all the divs and it didn't do anything. Tried wrapping my @if conditional in a div based on the troubleshooting section of the livewire docs, but no joy.

Comment: Slapping `wire:key="{{ uniqid() }}"` on everything isn't really going to help. It's weird indeed, never seen something similar. Are you on v2 or v3? That said though, with the information you've given so far and the limited snippet, it's hard to reproduce, and there's nothing obviously wrong here that I can see.

Comment: Yeah, was grasping at straws a bit just trying to isolate a root cause. It seems that having an anchor tag wrapping the card while also having anchor tags in the card footer was causing it to freak out. I just went a different direction and added a "view" link to the card footer, and removed the wrapping anchor. Everything is working fine now, but it's not the design I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's simple: You have an anchor tag inside an anchor tag. Just like with `form` elements, that's **not** allowed. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13054959/14793358). It describes in more detail how browsers effectively try to enforce the HTML rules by changing the HTML structure. By the looks of things, you're better off changing the nested anchors to buttons or spans (with a `wire:click.prevent` (see [docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#event-modifiers)).